# Identity Server 4 With Social Login Hosted In Mvc Application

Tags: c#, identityserver4, google-authentication, facebook-authentication, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Anyone can easily add Social vendors authentication in Identity Server 4, it takes few minutes:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services ) {
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddXXX().AddYYY();
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle( "Google", options => {
            options.XXX = XXX;
        } )
        .AddFacebook( "Facebook", options => {
            options.XXX = XXX;
        } );
}
```

Then you add some configuration in the client application (it's Asp.Net Core MVC in our case)...

```
services.AddAuthentication( options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
} )
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect( OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.ZZZ = ZZZ;
});
```

... and you have "Social Login" working.
That's it - users try to enter a secured page, and being redirected to IDP Login Page with Social vendor buttons (e.g. Google, Facebook), and get redirected back to the secured page when authenticated.

My challenge is exactly here - I'd like to **host** this **Login page in the client application**, and not in the IS4.
Is it possible at all? What should be configured in IS4?
What should be changed in the client app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that would be difficult. IDSVR4 will generate a token based on the social login. How would you generate that token if you bypass IDSVR?

What you should do is to create links e.g. to Google/Facebook in the MVC app that redirects to IDSVR url (specific to Google/facebook e.g "/login/facebook"), that again redirects to the correct provider, redirects back to IDSVR and again back to MVC app.

The user will not know that they are going through IDSVR.

Comment: My intention is to host a page with Social vendor buttons only, not the vendor login pages themselves. 
So the flow will be as following: 
Navigating to Secured page (in app) >> 
Redirect to the page with Social buttons (in app) >> 
Clicking the button will Redirect to the Social vendor >> 
Authenticate >> 
Redirect back to the secured page

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do, but in this scenario there is no place for IdentityServer. If you want IdentityServer to handle token generation, you MUST go through IdentityServer before redirecting to social login.